# Microphone Input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microphone

I have seen a lot of questions and articles about getting user's microphone input, but what I want is actually the opposite.

Is it possible to send a sound through the microphone as if the user himself had spoken? It would be something like soundpad, using JS.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "send a sound through the microphone"? You want to send a sound from a JS application to another application?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

When the user wants a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) with the microphone audio, they make a call to `navigator.getUserMedia({video:false, audio:true});`. We can redefine `navigator.getUserMedia` to our own function (keeping the original in a separate global variable so we can still get the microphone data) that will return a MediaStream which plays audio from a file. We can even return a combined MediaStream that will combine audio from the microphone and a file using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to do the combining.

I've been trying to do this with video so I can replace my video in Google Meet, but Google Meet seems to automatically do things to the MediaStream (like muting and pausing) that I haven't handled, so that project doesn't work yet. Google Meet is very secure, so that might be the problem, but I think this trick might work for you!